# Time from gettimeofday not updating as it should

Tags: c, gettimeofday

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int main()
{
   float time;
   struct timeval tv;
   gettimeofday( &tv, NULL );
   time = tv.tv_sec + ( tv.tv_usec / 1000000.0 );
   printf( "time: %f\n", time );
   return 0;
}
```

Running binary generated by this code repeatedly, I tend to get the same time value:

```
$ ./a.out
time: 1348059520.000000
$ ./a.out
time: 1348059520.000000
$ ./a.out
time: 1348059520.000000
```

This happens until several seconds later at which I get an updated time value.

Comment: `int main()` is undefined behavior. This is C, where `()` is not the same as `(void)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that `float` is too small to contain the result of `tv.tv_sec + ( tv.tv_usec / 1000000.0 )`. Use `double` instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int main()
{
   double time;
   struct timeval tv;
   gettimeofday( &tv, NULL );
   time = tv.tv_sec + ( tv.tv_usec / 1000000.0 );
   printf( "time: %f\n", time );
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not only 'appears' — that is precisely the trouble.  `float` can store 6-7 decimal digits; the time stamp at second level needs 10 decimal digits in the integer portion of the time, so to get 6 decimal places too, you need 16 decimal digits, which is just in range of `double` (assuming IEEE 754 floating point arithmetic).

Comment: +1 _Never_ put time in a `float`. Always use a `double` or `time_t`, as I've learnt the hard way. P.s. With gcc's (and other compiler's) shadow warnings, one shouldn't use `time` as a variable name.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you use floating point at all?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int main (void)
{
   struct timeval tv;
   gettimeofday (&tv, NULL);
   printf ("time: %d.%06d\n", (int)tv.tv_sec, (int)tv.tv_usec);
   return 0;
}

./a.out
time: 1348067289.069908
```

It *looks* floaty, but it's *inty* :-) Since the microseconds value is in the range 0..999999 all you need to do is zero-pad it to 6 digits. No FP arithmetic required.

Comment: By the way, I like this answer MUCH better as a way to accomplish what OP wants, but Tshepang's answer better explains the mechanism of the specific problem OP encountered. +1 to both, anyway.